# Anonymous users cannot see listed Commerce products in a View with a relationship to product

Tags: 7, commerce, views

Commerce products when listed in a View with a relatioinship to Commerce Products cannot be seen by anonymous users. I am using the Views Reference module in the product display and the View is not showing up when logged out. I cannot seem to find any permissions relating to this setup.

Comment: I'm not sure this post is really helpful on Stack Exchange, as it's not asking a question with a definitive answer. There's a whole thread about this in the issue queue, and the answer you supply below could result in stores giving away more information about their products than they intend. See: http://drupal.org/node/1276450

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default commerce products do not give anonymous permissions to be viewable. This is the reason when a View contains Commerce product relationships it will show nothing when your logged out. You will have to give users the permission setting:

--- **View any product of any type** ---

[image]

Comment: What about the security implications of this permission?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your view to disable node_access() checks.
In you view, click on the Query settings:

[image: click query settings]

Then check the Disable SQL rewriting checkbox.

Disabling node_access() may introduce security issues, but I think it should be ok for a acrefully constructed view.